Usage of .. not returning expected absolute path
We have a Spring Boot backend application (serviceA) that retrieves data from JSON files located on the same machine.
The location of the serviceA application jar is:
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceA.jar

The location of the JSON files is:
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/data1.json
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/data2.json
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/data3.json

serviceA retrieves the path with:
Path jsonPath = Paths.get("../serviceAJSONFiles/" + dataId + ".json").toAbsolutePath();

The path will get resolved as:
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/dataId.json

This change is not working in Java 17 environments however, with the FileNotFoundException exception being thrown.
We noticed the exception was showing up only in Java 17 environments, but this change was working fine in Java 8 dev & qa environments.
In Java 17 environments, the path was resolved to:
/usr/mware/backend/serviceA/../PreEditJSONFiles/dataId.json

We have since changed how data from the JSON files are retrieved by using the following:
String jsonFilePath = "/usr/mware/backend/";
...
Paths.get(jsonFilePath + dataId + ".json").toAbsolutePath();

Is anyone able to provide insight for this behavior? Thanks in advance.
This is Spring Boot 2.6.9

are you fetching data from http endpoint or absolute path?

I wonder how "/usr/mware/backend/" + dataId + ".json" can work if the files are in /usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/ (unless dataId == "serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/data1", in which case the previous attempt Paths.get("../serviceAJSONFiles/" + dataId + ".json") cannot work)  -- also wonder that it gets resolved to /usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/dataId.json is it really "dataId"? That would explain why it is not finding "data1.json"

Anyway .. will always be relative to the working directory - is it the same when running with Java 8 and with Java 17 ?

What is “this change” you are talking about? What did you change?

@silentsudo fetching data from a JSON file using an absolute path

@user85421 regarding your first comment, dataId will always be data1, data2, etc. it is not "/usr/mware/backend/" + dataId + ".json", you can refer to the details i shared in the question. regarding your second comment, we will add a logging statement to verify this but it is very likely the working directory is different in Java 8 & Java 17 environments, as the path is resolved to /usr/mware/backend/serviceA/serviceAJSONFiles/dataId.json in Java 8 while /usr/mware/backend/serviceA/../PreEditJSONFiles/dataId.json in Java 17

@Holger apologies, i was a bit loose with my words, "this change" simply refers to removing the use of .. & using an absolute path

'it is not "/usr/mware/backend/" + dataId + ".json"'?? How is String jsonFilePath = "/usr/mware/backend/"; ... Paths.get(jsonFilePath + dataId + ".json")..., the last posted snippet code, expect to work then? I may not know/use Spring-Boot, but that is standard Java

(unless the ... between setting jsonFilePath and calling Paths.get() is changing jsonFilePath)
